# Как узнать логин пользователя текущей графической сессии из демона в Astra Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, x11, astra-linux

Собственно демон из **init.d** запускается через **execaps**. Требуется в рантайме определять логин текущего пользователя графической сессии.
Пробовал искать в **QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment()**, только рутовые переменные окружения.
Пытался использовать **QX11Info::appScreen()** для дальнейшего парсинга **who -u**. Выдаёт номер дисплея, в котором запущен демон.
Какие идеи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> узнать логин пользователя текущей графической сессии

вообще это задача **весьма** нетривиальная.

даже если ограничиться лишь требованиями:

1. что графику отрисовывает именно программа *xorg*
2. причём запущенная «каноническим» способом каким-нибудь менеджером дисплеев (*dm*, *display manager*)
3. причём подключены к ней процессы только одного пользователя

всё равно остаётся достаточно «подводных камней».

---

пошагово (примеры команд приведены для программы *bash* для простоты — на языке *c/c++* они были бы очень громоздкими; примеры вывода у вас, конечно, могут и будут отличаться):

1. получить номер активного в данный момент виртуального терминала:

   ```
   $ sudo fgconsole
   7
   ```
2. получить номер процесса, запущенного на этом вирт. терминале (перед номером надо добавить строку `tty`:

   ```
   $ pgrep -t tty7
   650
   ```

   (это как раз и будет *x-сервер*, процесс, запущенный программой *xorg*)
3. извлечь из командной строки данного процесса номер дисплея (`:0`, `:1` и т.д.):

   ```
   $ grep -z '^:[0-9]\+$' /proc/650/cmdline
   :0
   ```
4. найти процессы, в переменных окружения которых присутствует строка `DISPLAY=<найденный номер>` (выводится список файлов `/proc/*/environ`, содержащих переменные окружения):

   ```
   $ sudo grep -zl '^DISPLAY=:0$' /proc/*/environ
   /proc/9908/environ
   ...
   ```
5. дополнить команду получением владельцев этих файлов, убрать упоминания root-а, оставить только первую строку:

   ```
   $ sudo grep -zl '^DISPLAY=:0$' /proc/*/environ | xargs stat -c '%U' 2>/dev/null | grep -v root | head -n 1
   user
   ```

   вот мы и получили имя пользователя. удача!

---

в принципе, после шага 3 (на котором мы получили номер дисплея), можно, конечно, поискать этот номер и в выводе, например, программы *who*. но, по моему личному опыту, этот способ несколько менее надёжен:

- в столбце `line` может быть написан и номер дисплея (`:0`), и что-нибудь вроде `console`
- номер дисплея может присутствовать в столбце `comment`, а может и не упоминаться
- вполне возможны ситуации, когда в [utmp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp) (откуда черпает информацию программа *who*) по какой-либо причине не отмечено событие logout-а пользователя, и в случае, когда несколько пользователей работают попеременно, в выводе *who* может присутствовать более одной строки с упоминанием одного и того же дисплея, но с разными пользователями.

---

стоит ещё отметить, что переменные окружения контролируются процессом, которому они принадлежат, и, в общем, ничто не мешает какому-нибудь процессу взять и добавить себе переменную окружения `DISPLAY` с произвольным значением. имейте это ввиду.

Comment: У меня, к сожалению, на 3 этапе из строки **/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg-br-novtswitch-quiet:0vt7-nolistentcp-auth/var/run/xauth/A:0-sA8udauserc** ничего не выводит.
Демон, запущеный от рута, выдаёт правильный логин следующей командой, да простят меня знатоки bash:

**who | awk '{print $1 " " $2}' | grep $(ps aux | grep Xorg | grep $(cat /sys/class/tty/tty0/active) | awk '{print $15}') | awk '{print $1}'** при паре существующих графических сессий.

Comment: там не строка, там много строк, разделённых нулевыми символами (для того и опция `-z` у программы *grep*)