# Как исправить ошибку Failed to open X11 display при запуске графической программы SFML?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, sfml

Ошибка: Failed to open X11 display; make sure the DISPLAY environment variable is set correctly
Аварийный останов (стек памяти сброшен на диск)

Comment: а как именно Вы это все запускаете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том что в линуксе дисплей штука совсем не обязательная, или она может даже находиться совсем на другом компьютере. То что ты видишь на экране реализовано через отдельную программу называется она X11 Server. Так вот твоя SFML не знает куда ей присоединятся что-бы отрисовать своё окошко. Что-бы она узнала об этом нужно через `export` прописать переменную окружения `DISPLAY` с портом X11 сервера.

Вот тут можно посмотреть много дополнительной инфы про то как с этой переменной работать. https://datacadamia.com/ssh/x11/display

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что запуск идёт из под крона. Если так, то для запуска графических приложений кроном нужно писать нечто вроде:

```
* * 10 0 * export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/somedirectory/somecommand
```

Comment: В линуксе не надо писать export для установки переменных окружения просто `DISPLAY=:0 /bin/command` И с каких это пор крон не получает переменные окружения своего пользователя? И с каких это пор  GUI приложения запускают из под крона? )))

Comment: @EugeneX, `И с каких это пор крон не получает переменные окружения своего пользователя?` переменные окружения передаются от родителя потомкам. процесс *cron* со 100-процентной вероятностью запущен не тем же самым процессом (или его потомком), что запустил процесс *Xorg*.

Comment: @Sergey ваш ответ не универсален примерно полностью. начать хотя бы с того, что процессов *Xorg* может быть и ноль, и больше одного.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin - "ваш ответ не универсален примерно полностью" - разумеется. **не** универсален. Я понимаю Вашу критику так, что у Вас есть **универсальное** решение? Можно с ним ознакомиться?  А то вот я, по своему скудомыслию, пользуюсь этим **не** универсальным приёмом уже лет 15 и на Ubuntu и на SuSe и на Fedora...  Запускаю разного рода бэкапы, напоминалки и т.д. и ничего... Работает :-)

Comment: совсем универсального решения, пожалуй, не существует. даже лишь чуть более универсальное уже довольно монструозно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/819677/178576 // я намекал в первую очередь на то, что имеет смысл изложить в ответе хотя бы основные оговорки/ограничения.

Comment: впрочем, если ваше предположение об использовании *cron* верно, то более подходящим советом может быть рекомендация использовать *at*.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin - "имеет смысл изложить в ответе хотя бы основные оговорки/ограничения." - Наверное, Вы правы.